# ORA -06502 while executing a procedure dynamically

Tags: oracle

In a certain code we are using dbms_sql to dynamically execute a procedure ..

There is  a variable , let' say k, which we are binding to an output value of the proc  ,let's say ot1 .

We are doing it as follow :

```
Dbms_sql.bind_variable ( cur , 'ot1', k, 2048)
```

And then executing the proc as follow :

```
Dbms_output.execute(cur)
```

And the  fetching the value of ot1  as follow :

```
Dbms_sql.variable_value(cur , 'ot1' , k)
```

`Ot1` is of type varchar2 and is the output param to the proc being executed .

`K` is also of type varchar2.

On executing /testing the proc in db with same  input parameters the value of `ot1` is "300"
But when executed dynamically as mentioned above  I am getting   **ora-06502**  at

```
Dbms_sql.variable_value( cur , 'ot1, k)
```

For other inputs the values are like "400" , "250" etc but in those cases this error is not coming ..

**ora 06502** occurs when there is an oveflow but for a varchar2 output parameter this cannot be an overflow since the value is 300 only and no such error is seen for values 400, 500 , 250

And this , I don't feel to be , a type mismatch  since the output value can be treated as a string ..and such errors are not seen with other output values like '400' and '250'.

What can be the issue here ?

Comment: Are you sure the problematic '300' value doesn't have (lots of) trailing spaces? When you query it manually can you check the actual length? And does the error stack indicate that the exception is being thrown inside the procedure you are calling, or as part of your dynamic call wrapper?

Comment: @AlexPoole : Yeah that is one possibility ..but are there any other possibilities resulting in this error ?

Comment: @AlexPoole Part of the dynamic call wrapper

Comment: Well, that seems like a fairly easy one to check... without seeing the full error stack and the relevant code it's hard to say what else might be happening. How is `k` itself declared?

Comment: @AlexPoole : Output parameter of the dynamic call wrapper , decalred as varchar 2

Comment: Please edit your question an include the complete text of the error message(s) you're getting. Thanks.